# Why a "barrier()" is enough for disabling or enabling the preemption?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, barrier, preemption

From Linux kernel code，I can see the `preempt_enable()` and `preempt_disable()` are nothing except just `barrier()`:

```
#define preempt_disable()       barrier()

#define preempt_enable()        barrier()
```

I can't understand it. Why just a `barrier()` is enough for disabling or enabling the preemption?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not using a preemptible Kernel.
A user space process is preemptible though.

Check if CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY is set in your kernel config.

See
[What is preemption / What is a preemtible kernel? What is it good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817059/what-is-preemption-what-is-a-preemtible-kernel-what-is-it-good-for)

The barrier was added since https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable/+/386afc91144b36b42117b0092893f15bc8798a80%5E!/

Answer (score 0):

In Kernel v4.3, the right definition for `preempt_enable` is [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/preempt.h#L180):

```
#define preempt_enable() \
do { \
    barrier(); \
    if (unlikely(preempt_count_dec_and_test())) \
           __preempt_schedule(); \
} while (0)
```

and similarly for `preempt_disable` is [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/preempt.h#L163):

```
#define preempt_disable() \
do { \
     preempt_count_inc(); \
     barrier(); \
} while (0)
```

`preempt_enable` inserts optimization barrier before preemption is enabled and `preempt_disable` inserts barrier after the preemption counter is incremented. However as per [comment](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/preempt.h#L231), when there is no preemption involved but just barriers to protect preempted region.

**EDIT**: In UP and non-preempt respectively, the spinlocks and preemption
disable/enable points are stubbed out entirely, because there is no
regular code that can ever hit the kind of concurrency they are meant to
protect against.

However, while there is no regular code that can cause scheduling, we
*do* end up having some exceptional (literally!) code that can do so,
and that we need to make sure does not ever get moved into the critical
region by the compiler.

In particular, get_user() and put_user() is generally implemented as
inline asm statements (even if the inline asm may then make a call
instruction to call out-of-line), and can obviously cause a page fault
and IO as a result.  If that inline asm has been scheduled into the
middle of a preemption-safe (or spinlock-protected) code region, we
obviously lose.

Now, admittedly this is *very* unlikely to actually ever happen, and
we've not seen examples of actual bugs related to this.  But partly
exactly because it's so hard to trigger and the resulting bug is so
subtle, we should be extra careful to get this right.

So make sure that even when preemption is disabled, and we don't have to
generate any actual *code* to explicitly tell the system that we are in
a preemption-disabled region, we need to at least tell the compiler not
to move things around the critical region. [Source](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/kernel-team/2013-April/026826.html)

Comment: [preempt_disable](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/preempt.h#L163)'s implementation requires `CONFIG_PREEMPT_COUNT` is on, [This](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/preempt.h#L236)(`#define preempt_disable()  barrier()`) is the version  when `CONFIG_PREEMPT_COUNT` is off.

Comment: To add to the above mentioned description, kernel can be compiled in two ways, namely preemptive mode and non preemptive mode. (I'm  not taking about userspace preemption which is always there). Kconfig [source] (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/Kconfig.preempt)  that controls the enable/disable of preemption. When we enable CONFIG_PREEMPT, CONFIG_PREEMPT_COUNT is automatically enabled (refer kconfig.preempt). When PREEMPT is disabled, the calles are replaced by barrier() which just to flush writes to DRAM.